# Orphans rows due to Missing Foreign keys

Tags: sql, azure, azure-devops, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2019

I have composite foreign key missing in Production and when tried to create gave error "Alter table conflicted with foreign key constraint".

Below is the statement we are trying to execute.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_ComputationWebsheetCellData WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_ComputationWebsheetCellData_tbl_ComputationWebsheetCell] 
        FOREIGN KEY (ComputationID, CustomScheduleID, AccountGUID, ColumnGUID) 
        REFERENCES [tbl_ComputationWebsheetCell] (ComputationID, CustomScheduleID, AccountGUID, ColumnGUID)
```

Below are the tables details:

```
tbl_ComputationWebsheetCellData

--PK_tbl_ComputationWebsheetCellData (ComputationID, CustomScheduleID, AccountGUID, ColumnGUID)
--FK_tbl_ComputationWebsheetCellData_tbl_ComputationWebsheetCell 
 REFERENCES dbo.tbl_ComputationWebsheetCell (ComputationID, CustomScheduleID, AccountGUID, ColumnGUID)
tbl_ComputationWebsheetCell

--PK_tbl_ComputationWebsheetCell  (ComputationID, CustomScheduleID, AccountGUID, ColumnGUID)
```

Will the below script give the orphan rows?

```
select top 10 celldata.*
 from tbl_ComputationWebsheetCellData (nolock) celldata
 left join tbl_ComputationWebsheetCell(nolock) cell
 On celldata.ComputationID = cell.ComputationID
 and celldata.CustomScheduleID = cell.CustomScheduleID
 and celldata.AccountGUID = cell.AccountGUID
 and celldata.ColumnGUID = cell.ColumnGUID
 where cell.ComputationID IS NULL
 and cell.CustomScheduleID IS NULL
 and cell.AccountGUID Is NULL
 and cell.ColumnGUID IS NULL
```

Comment: A `NOT EXISTS` maybe? Why are you using `NOLOCK`?

Comment: Nolock as i need to fetch data from prod.

Comment: Why does that mean you need to use `NOLOCK`? It has serious implications for data integrity, perhaps you should be using `SNAPSHOT` isolation instead